# Sharing sensor analog output with multiple ADC for digitization

Tags: analog, adc, sample-and-hold

I am using a pressure sensor, MPVZ4006GW6U, and I have an unique requirement where by I need to share this sensor's output with multiple ADC (say ADC128 from TI) for digitization. Each ADC is interfaced with different microcontrollers for processing the digitized values and hence the need.

1. Will there be any functional issues when an analog signal is fed to multiple devices?
2. Does the analog signal sharing arrangement disturb the sample and hold stage internal to the ADC?
3. What are the things to be taken care of in the layout while T-routing this analog signal?

Answer (score 2):

If you provide sufficient drive into the ADCs, this will work without problems.

In order to prevent the Sample-and-Hole HF noise from travelling along the shared path and into another ADC, you should add RC input filters to each ADC. But this is a good practise even without having multiple ADC inputs.

Comment: "Sufficient drive" may mean adding a buffer amplifier between the sensor and the ADCs, which will add its own sources of error (noise, offset, etc.) to the measurements.

Comment: It looks like that sensor already has an integrated amplifier, cf. page 4 of the datashet.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why you can't share the digital data among the MCUs.

Comment: Seriously? Surely calibrating and synchronizing multiple ADCs is a bigger firmware problem than sharing a few bytes of data is.